# PERL calculate and output ratio adjusted time series ( OHLC ) from two input files

Tags: perl

> I wish to merge two one minute time
>   series files with PERL and adjusting
>   the input data to output a ratio
>   adjusted time series.
>
> I am having troubles with reading two
>   files at the same time and designing the control (loop?) architecture.
>
> I need to able to read one line from FileA and one line from fileB and
>   compare the date and time values. From
>   there will either calculate the
>   adjusted time series.

```
    my $cntA = 1 ;
    my $cntB = 1 ;

    if ($cntA == 1 ) { 
        unlink ("$rATS");

        #open files
        open(FA, $fileA) or die "Error opening data file: $fileA $!\n"; 
        open(FB, $fileB) or die "Error opening data file: $fileB $!\n";

        open(MYOUTFILE, ">> $rATS") || die("unable to open $fileName");
        #header
        print MYOUTFILE "Date,Time,Open,High,Low,Close\n";

    }

    =item
        #possible controlling loop 
        foreach my $SymA (@filesA){ 
            foreach my $SumB (@filesB){
                print "$filesASym  $filesBSym\n"; 
    =cut


    while (<FA>) {  
        my @fieldsA  = split /,/,$_;
        #if ($fieldsA[0] != $DateA) { $closeYA = $CloseA ;}
        my $DateA       = $fieldsA[0] ;
        my $TimeA       = $fieldsA[1] ;
        my $OpenA       = $fieldsA[2] ;
        my $HighA       = $fieldsA[3] ;
        my $LowA        = $fieldsA[4] ;
        my $CloseA      = $fieldsA[5] ;
        my $VolumeA     = $fieldsA[6] ;
        my $OpenIntA    = $fieldsA[7] ;


        my $lineNumA = $. ;
        print "line num A: $lineNumA\n\n";

        $cntA++;
        last if $cntA != 0 ;
    }

    while (<FB>) {  
        my @fieldsB  = split /,/,$_;
        #if ($fieldsB[0] != $DateB) { $closeYB = $CloseB ;}
        my $DateB       = $fieldsB[0] ;
        my $TimeB       = $fieldsB[1] ;
        my $OpenB       = $fieldsB[2] ;
        my $HighB       = $fieldsB[3] ;
        my $LowB        = $fieldsB[4] ;
        my $CloseB      = $fieldsB[5] ;
        my $VolumeB     = $fieldsB[6] ;
        my $OpenIntB    = $fieldsB[7] ;

        $cntB++;
        last if $cntB != 0 ;
    }

    close(FA)           || die("unable to close $fileA") ;
    close(FB)           || die("unable to close $fileB") ;
    close(MYOUTFILE)    || die("unable to close $fileName") ;

    =item

sub ratio ($$) {
    my $ratioAB;

    if ($_[0] > $_[1])  { $ratioAB = eval { $_[1] / $_[0]; } ; } warn $@ if $@ ;
    if ($_[0] <= $_[0]) { $ratioAB = eval { $_[0] / $_[1]; } ; } warn $@ if $@ ;  
    return  sprintf("%.2f", $ratioAB) ;
}

sub calcOHLC {
    if ($closeYA > $closeYB) {  
        $open  = sprintf("%.2f",$ratio * $openA - $openB);
        $close = sprintf("%.2f",$ratio * $closeA - $closeB);
        $high  = sprintf("%.2f",$ratio * $highA - $highB); 
        $low   = sprintf("%.2f",$ratio * $lowA - $lowB); 
    }

    if ($closeYA <= $closeYB ) { 
        $open  = sprintf("%.2f",$openA - $ratio * $openB);
        $close = sprintf("%.2f",$closeA - $ratio * $closeB);
        $high  = sprintf("%.2f",$highA - $ratio * $highB);
        $low   = sprintf("%.2f",$lowA - $ratio * $lowB);
    }
    return undef;
}

    sub outputFile{
        print MYOUTFILE "$Date" . "," . "$Time" . "," . "$Open" . "," . "$High" . "," . "$Low" . "," . "$Close" . "\n";
    }
    =cut
```

Sample Data:

```
    CVX File:
    1/28/2011   957     94.21   94.21   94      94      83424   1357498
    1/28/2011   958     94.02   94.11   94.02   94.1    41351   1398849
    1/28/2011   959     94.1    94.11   94.06   94.1    27715   1426564
    1/28/2011   1000    94.1    94.11   94.06   94.1    27715   1426564
    1/28/2011   1001    94.18   94.2    94.04   94.07   61584   1523943
    1/28/2011   1002    94.07   94.2    94.04   94.06   67352   1591295
    1/28/2011   1003    94.07   94.2    94.04   94.06   67352   1591295
    1/28/2011   1004    94.09   94.16   94.02   94.12   42852   1684278

    XOM File:
    1/28/2011   957     79.59   79.59   79.53   79.55   78759   1997094
    1/28/2011   958     79.59   79.59   79.53   79.55   78759   1997094
    1/28/2011   959     79.62   79.64   79.58   79.58   77559   2107813
    1/28/2011   1000    79.58   79.6    79.58   79.6    87640   2195453
    1/28/2011   1001    79.6    79.61   79.54   79.55   88442   2283895
    1/28/2011   1002    79.6    79.61   79.54   79.55   88442   2283895
    1/28/2011   1003    79.57   79.59   79.55   79.57   54073   2408315
    1/28/2011   1004    79.57   79.58   79.5    79.52   118655  2526970

    ratio as of 1/27/2011 = 79.88/94.75 = .84 
    since CVX is higher XOM/CVX
    (CVX * .84) - XOM for output on 1/28/2011

    Output file
    Date        time    open    high    low     close
    1/28/2011   957     -0.45   -0.45   -0.57   -0.59
    1/28/2011   958     -0.61   -0.54   -0.55   -0.51
    1/28/2011   959     -0.58   -0.59   -0.57   -0.54
    1/28/2011   1000    -0.54   -0.55   -0.57   -0.56
    1/28/2011   1001    -0.49   -0.48   -0.55   -0.53
    1/28/2011   1002    -0.58   -0.48   -0.55   -0.54
    1/28/2011   1003    -0.55   -0.46   -0.56   -0.56
    1/28/2011   1004    -0.53   -0.49   -0.52   -0.46
```

Comment: It sounds like you are asking people to write your entire program for you. If so, SO is the wrong place for this. If not, I would recommend two things: #1 If you don't even know how to approach the solution programmatically (e.g. have no pseudocode algorithm), you can try and ask but again, SO is the wrong venue. If you DO have a pseudocode, you can post a series of questions of type "I tried to write code X (add example) in Perl and have problem Y, what can I do to fix" or "I have this piece of logic in pseudocide, how do I do it in Perl?"

Comment: P.S. On the other hand, if what you are describing in your question is some sort of standard algorithm, and you're asking "Is there a CPAN module implementing it", then you should post at the top an executive summary with a link to algorithm's official description, and whether you have tried to search CPAN for that algorithm.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to post this on rentacoder.com?

Comment: I posted my code, mea culpa. I certainly do not wish to insult or be inappropriate. If it seems so, please let me know and I will do what is right. If there is something on CPAN that does this I can't find it ( or recognize that the module does what I need ).

Comment: The code I posted has some oddities to it, and is certainly not functional as is. The primary issue I face is how to create the appropriate loop (s) in order to process fileA and fileB and have both a line from each to calc, yet keep some sort of master loop iterating.

Comment: Doug Johnson, I upvoted your question back to 0. You have a better chance for getting answers when you once more edit it and cut away the non-essential complexity to better display your problem mentioned in the last comment.

Comment: @Doug - much better as far as community standards! I will try to fix your formatting which makes the code look problematic at the moment. However, as a potential answerer, I will probably skip it on "TL;DR" grounds ("Too Long Didn't Read") - You run a MUCH higher likelyhood of getting help if you try to break up your question into smaller issues.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. It is verbose and it is difficult for me to keep whittling down. Is there a more articulate way of describing the problem I face? I will look at individual file handling rather than multiples in CPAN, there may be something I missed.

Comment: @Doug - your last attempt was probably good enough, assuming my comprehension of it (as evidenced by my answer) is correct :)

Comment: +1 for great effort to improve the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit unclear what you mean by "in order to process fileA and fileB and have both a line from each to calc, yet keep some sort of master loop iterating".

if you mean that you wish to advance in 2 files in parallel, you can do it fairly easily - keep 1 loop, and read 1 line from each file per iteration. My code below is a bit vague since I don't know what you want to do

```
my ($done, $done_with_A, $done_with_B, $lineA, $lineB) = (0, 0, 0);
while (!$done_with_A || !$done_with_B) {
    if (!$done_with_A) {
        $lineA = <FA>;
    }
    if (!$done_with_B) {
        $lineB = <FB>;
    }
    ($done_with_A, $done_with_B) = are_we_done($lineA, $lineB); 
             # $lineA, $lineB are undef when the files are done.
    process($lineA, $lineB);
}
```

If you need to be able to possibly process several lines from fileA for 1 line for fileB (or vice versa), its a bit more complicated  - you accumulate lines in buffers:

```
my ($done, $read_from_A, $read_from_B, $done_with_A, $done_with_B, $lineA, $lineB) = (0, 1, 1, 0, 0);
my (@buffer_A, @buffer_B);
while (!$done_with_A || !$done_with_B) {
    if (!$done_with_A && $need_to_read_from_A) {
        $lineA = <FA>;
    }
    if (!$done_with_B && $need_to_read_from_B) {
        $lineB = <FB>;
    }
    ($done_with_A, $done_with_B) = are_we_done($lineA, $lineB); 
             # $lineA, $lineB are undef when the files are done.
    if ( need_more_lines_from_A($lineA, $lineB) ) {
        $read_from_A = 1;
        $read_from_B = 0; # $lineB stays the same
        push @buffer_A, $lineA;
        next;
    }
    if ( need_more_lines_from_B($lineA, $lineB) ) {
        $read_from_A = 0; # $lineA stays the same
        $read_from_B = 1; 
        push @buffer_B, $lineB;
        next;
    }
    push @buffer_A, $lineA;
    push @buffer_B, $lineB;
    process(@buffer_A, @buffer_A);
    @buffer_B = (); @buffer_B = (); # Reset the buffers
    $read_from_A = 0; $read_from_B = 0; # Read next batch.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, DVK. I believe you have the elegant solution. Easier than I thought. Let me process over the weekend.

Comment: @Doug - good luck :)   if it helps, feel free to up-vote the answer (up arrow next to it) and mark it as accepted (checkmark next to it)